# Problem with External S3 Source in Assets 2.1.3 and EE 2.5.5

Tags: ee2, assets, php, error

I get the following error when attempting to save an external source using Assets 2.1.3 in EE 2.5.5:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::result_array() in 
/home/active/public_html/administrate-am/codeigniter/system/libraries/Javascript.php 
on line 765
```

Anyone have any idea how to fix this? It looks like it's an issue with generating JSON, but I don't know how to fix it and it's kind of urgent.

PHP 5.3.x, in case it matters.

Comment: Can you shoot some FTP/CP credentials over to support@pixelandtonic.com?

Comment: @BradBell - Sent!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in Assets and will be fixed in the next release.

In the meantime, the patch is:

in mcp.assets.php in the save_source() method, line 1000 is:

```
$data = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'settings' => Assets_helper::get_json((object) $save_data)
);
```

I changed it to:

```
$data = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'settings' => Assets_helper::get_json($save_data)
);
```