# Assets and Rackspace White screen on save

Tags: assets, cloudfiles

I am trying to add rackspace cloud files to assets, but when saving I get white screen. Any ideas why?

EE 2.5.5
Assets 2.1.3

I have tried with amazon s3 , and private and public repos on both to test.

Comment: Does the save complete? Does the file still get sent to Rackspace or does it just hang? Also have you double checked your access credentials and made sure that you've indexed before trying to upload?

Comment: Have you turned the debug on? Admin > Output & Debugging > Debug Preference

Comment: Oliver - saving what exactly do you get a white screen?

Comment: The save does not complete, I enter all the details that all seem correct, it finds the correct bucket etc but when clicking save (to save the external source as a folder to upload to) I get the white screen

Comment: Turned on debugging and get this error

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::result_array() in /path/to/server/system/codeigniter/system/libraries/Javascript.php on line 765`

Comment: Found the answer here and there is a bug

[http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/10523/861][1]


  [1]: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/10523/861

Answer (score 2):

Try uploading using the native File module and verify that the directory is in fact writable by EE.